# necesito enviar token bearer desde ajax JQUERY

Tags: jquery, ajax

tengo un problema...tengo una petición ajax jquery a un webapi que espera un token. Agrego la cabecera Authorization Bearer+Token pero éste no llega al web api...expongo el código:

```
        $.ajax({
        url : 'http://localhost:59596/Prueba',
        data : {},
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        success : function(json) {
           debugger;
        },
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) { 
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Bearer 93854545454545454' );
        },
        error : function(xhr, status) {
            alert('Disculpe, existió un problema');
        },
        complete : function(xhr, status) {
            alert('Petición realizada');
        }
    });
```

También lo he probado de esta forma:

```
        $.ajax({
        url : 'http://localhost:59596/Prueba',
        data : {},
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        success : function(json) {
           debugger;
        },
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) { 
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Bearer 93854545454545454' );
        },
        error : function(xhr, status) {
            alert('Disculpe, existió un problema');
        },
        complete : function(xhr, status) {
            alert('Petición realizada');
        }
    });
```

De ninguna forma llega...lo más curioso es que desde postman, llega

Comment: Lo conseguiste solucionar colega? yo estoy en ello...

Answer (score 3):

Intenta con esto:

```
$.ajax({
  url : 'http://localhost:59596/Prueba',
  data : {},
  dataType : 'jsonp',
  // Añade un header:
  headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer 93854545454545454'},
  // El resto del código
  success : function(json) {
     debugger;
  }
  ...
});
```

Según la [documentación de jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), este método tiene una opción llamada `headers` la cual permite agregar (valga la redundancia) headers a los llamados. Según la documentación, `headers` es "un objecto de headers adicionales (de la forma llave/valor) que se envían con las solicitudes usando XMLHttpRequest".

Comment: Esta forma sí funciona, materile lirero. :D